# Creating dynamic array in c gives error at realloc()

Tags: c, arrays, dynamic, compiler-warnings, realloc

I'm trying to write a dynamic array in C and I almost did it.Now I' stuck at a point where it gives error while inserting in that error using realloc().Here is my code:

```
   #include<stdio.h>
   #include<stdlib.h>

   typedef struct {

     int *array;//pointer that points to the start of the contiguous  allocated blocks(an array of int)

     size_t used;//array used

     size_t size;//array total size
   }D_Array;


   void alloc_array(D_Array *a, int initial_size)
  {
    //allocate contiguous memory blocks and point a pointer to its beginning address...
    a->array = (int*)malloc(initial_size*sizeof(int));
    a->used = 0;
    a->size = initial_size;
  }


  void insert_array(D_Array *a, int element)
  {
   if(a->used == a->size)
   {
    //allocate one more space and then insert in array
    a->array = (int*)relloc(a->array,(a->size)*sizeof(int)); 
   }
    a->array[a->used++] = element;
  }


  void free_array(D_Array *a)
  {
   free(a->array);
   a->array = NULL;
   a->used = a->size = 0;
  }

  int main()
  {

   D_Array a; 
   int i=0, initial_size=0, insert_element=0;

   printf("Enter the initial size of array :");
   scanf("%d",&initial_size);
   alloc_array(&a, initial_size);

   printf("\nEnter the elements to be inserted initially");
   for(i=0 ; i<initial_size ; ++i)
   {
    scanf("%d",&insert_element);
    insert_array(&a, insert_element);
   }
    a.array[0] = 3;
   for(i=0 ; i<initial_size ; ++i)
   {
    printf("%d",*((a.array)+i));
   }
  }
```

Problem is in method "insert_array" but I don't know why.Everything seems fine to me.

[update from [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37371248/creating-dynamic-array-in-c-gives-error-at-realloc#comment62254398_37371248):]

The compiler gives:

```
quicksort.c:32:14: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast] a->array = (int*)relloc(a->array,(a->size)*sizeof(int)); ^ /tmp/ccXTwlHh.o: In function insert_array': quicksort.c:(.text+0x8d): undefined reference to relloc' collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: quicksort.c:32:14: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
   a->array = (int*)relloc(a->array,(a->size)*sizeof(int)); 
              ^
/tmp/ccXTwlHh.o: In function `insert_array':
quicksort.c:(.text+0x8d): undefined reference to `relloc'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: doesn't `a->array[a->used++] = element;` cause out of bound access since `a->used == a->size` ?

Comment: @bkVnet No it shouldn't....suppose he size is 3 and "used" is 0.Now it will insert at '0' index and increment 'used' then it will insert at '1' and increment 'used'...again it will insert at '2' and increment 'used'....Now 'used is '3' and 'size' is 3.So it will enter the 'if' and reallocate one more block and then insert again.

Comment: if `size` is 3 then `used` is also 3 because `a->used == a->size` according to your code and in the `if` block it allocate a memory block of 3 since `size` is 3 and now so is `used`. Next you are accessing `a->array[3]` on an array which has 3 elements which is out of bound.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding to what's been said, you've written `relloc` instead of `realloc`. So there is perhaps a typo which is hindering the compilation.

Comment: Such a silly mistake from my side.....its done..Thanks a lot...deserve some down votes for sure......

Answer (score 4):

There are two problems with your `realloc` call: The first is what will happen if `realloc` fails and returns `NULL`. That's the reason you should never reassign to the variable you pass to the `realloc` call.

The second problem, and what's probably causing your problem, is that that you don't actually *resize* the array, instead you reallocate it using the exact same size as before, meaning that when you next do

```
a->array[a->used++] = element;
```

you are indexing out of bounds and will have *undefined behavior*.

Comment: So how should I use realloc() in this case? Suppose I have 5 blocks of memory that I have created using malloc().The "array" pointer points to the  address of first block.Now when I use realloc() like I have used here,isn't it supposed to create a new contagious block of memory?

Comment: @Reckoner it does but you are not increasing the size of the memory block but just reallocating with the same size. You need to increase the value of `a->size` before calling it. That is of course once you correct the `relloc` typo :)

Comment: @Reckoner You have already allocated `a->size` elements using `malloc`, then the `realloc` call reallocates `a->size` number of elements. You must increase `a->size` before reallocating.

Comment: Sorry if I'm wrong but let's go back to the basics......here is a sample code that I've written to check what you are saying:

{
  int *ptr;
  ptr = (int*)malloc(1*sizeof(int));
  *ptr = 10;
  ptr = (int*)realloc(ptr,1*sizeof(int));
  ++ptr;
  
  printf("%p",ptr);
  
  --ptr;
  printf("%p",ptr);
return 0;
}

Now tell me the difference between the 2 codes here:
In this sample code,I am expecting to add a contiguous memory block using realloc() and it does what I expect....any problems in this code?

Comment: @Reckoner The code in the comment is not a problem because you don't dereference the pointer `ptr` out of bounds. The problem with the code in the question is that you don't do e.g. `a->size += 10` *before* the call to `realloc`. In your question you allocate X bytes. Then you call `reallocae` to allocate X bytes *again*. Both the `malloc` and `realloc` call will allocate a chunk of contiguous memory, ***equally*** large.

Comment: @Reckoner Think of the memory you allocate as an array of `a->size` elements, and you trying to use `a->size + 1` elements.

Comment: @Joachim Pileborg  in the code in the comment i don't think `ptr` is even a pointer its declared as `int ptr` and the results of `malloc` and `realloc` are casted to `int` but if it was he is doing `++ptr` then calling `printf("%p",ptr);` isn't that dereferencing?

Comment: @bkVnet I assume that's just a typing error, and no printing the pointer using the `"%p"` format is not dereferencing the pointer, it's using the contents of the pointer variable itself, not what it points to.

Comment: @bkVnet its a typo......doesn't show asterik there when I copy paste the code and then post as a comment...dnno why?But its not an int but an int pointer

Comment: @JoachimPileborg yep, i didn't pick up on that.

Comment: @Joachim I guess I got what you are trying to say here.....So should I increase the value of 'size' as well when I am reallocating?

Comment: @Reckoner Yes that's correct. If you want to change the size of the allocated memory, you actually have to change the size. :)